# JSX React brackets comparing values

Tags: reactjs

Can someone expalain this code to me?  I am getting a (false && false && why are you comparing a hyperlink markup?

```
{id === constants.ACCOUNT_NO && sessionState['backBtnAddressDetails'] &&
<a href="#" onClick={handleLinkClick} className="cbLink">Confirm details</a>                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic that the chained `&&`s implement is: the final expression in the chain, that is, the

```
<a href="#" onClick={handleLinkClick} className="cbLink">Confirm details</a>
```

gets rendered only if the prior two expressions are truthy.

Another way of doing the same thing would be:

```
{showConfirmLink()}
```

```
const showConfirmLink = () => {
  if (id !== constants.ACCOUNT_NO || !sessionState['backBtnAddressDetails']) {
    return null; // don't render anything
  }
  return <a href="#" onClick={handleLinkClick} className="cbLink">Confirm details</a>;
};
```

Another example of this, outside of React:

```js
const theValue = 'abc' && true && 'theValue';
console.log(theValue);
```

If any of the expressions in an `&&` chain are falsey, the chain stops evaluating there, and the whole thing resolves to that falsey expression. Otherwise, it evaluates to the final expression in the chain.

Comment: This is using the fact that for `false` react will render nothing, so please note that if you use a variable that has the possibility to provide a falsy value that is also valid to render in react (i.e. a `0`) you might want to accompany it with a double bang, such as `!!someNumberVariable && <Component />` instead of `someNumberVariable && <Component />`, to ensure react will render nothing when the condition is falsy.

Comment: @CertainPerformance there was a bit more logic that I did not include due to compliance, but your solution allowed me to correct the issue.  Great write up.  Everyone thank you so much.  Gratitude is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

This type of expression is referred to as conditional rendering in React ,
basically if the condition is true, the element right (the `<a href="#" onClick={handleLinkClick} className="cbLink">Confirm details</a>`  element in your case ) after && will appear in the output. If it is false, React will ignore and skip it.

it could mean the id  and  constants.ACCOUNT_NO  aren't of the same type (when you use the  `===` operator  it strictly compares the types too )
another possibility is `sessionState['backBtnAddressDetails']` could be null

Comment: sessionState['backBtnAddressDetails'] is undefined, but I did validate that the id === constans.ACCOUNT_NO are true.   What is the just sessionState['backBtnAddressDetails'] comparing?